# Getting an NSDate to change the screen to black (night time viewing) Swift

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to get the time using NSDate in order to change the background of the app to black at night. How would I go about that? I need to see what time zone the person is in (if possible) or I could ask the person and store it in NSUserDefaults. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

"Dark" is a relative term. Day length can vary significantly depending on the user's location and the time of year. To get precise definition of dark, you need to get the sunrise and sunset times for the day from a weather service.

But if you want something simple, say 7PM - 6AM is dark, try this:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
let dateComponents = calendar.componentsInTimeZone(NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone(), fromDate: NSDate())

let isDark = dateComponents.hour >= 19 || dateComponents.hour <= 6
```